# No overload for method SetError

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012

i am kind of new to android and have the following problem:
here is the code:

```
 base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout1);
        Button butondata = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
        Button butonstartdate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
        Button butonenddate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button5);
        EditText txtsubiect = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        Button submit = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonsalveaza);

        butondata.Click += butondata_Click;

        submit.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                txtsubiect.TextChanged += (object sender1, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs f) =>
                    {


                        if (txtsubiect.Text.Length <= 0)
                        {
                            txtsubiect.RequestFocus();
                            txtsubiect.SetError("Eroare,camp gol!");
                        }
                    };
            };
```

When i build it,i t says this: No overload for method'SetError' takes 1 arguments ,what is wrong, because im kind of confused,and will the error message appear? Thx!

Comment: Is this Xamarin?  Have you looked at the documentation for EditText.SetError?

Comment: Yes it is Xamarin,and yes, i have read the documentation about seterror from here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: According to Xamarin's docs, `SetError` is inherited from `Android.Widget.TextView.SetError`, and there are two overloads, both of which take two arguments, not one: `SetError(Java.Lang.ICharSequence, Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable)` and `SetError(string, Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable)`.

Comment: [Android.Widget.TextView: Method Member](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.EditText%2fM) - You'll need to scroll down the list to see the two overloads of `SetError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a drawable to be displayed along with the error message.
It takes 2 arguments and the second is a Drawable, an icon to be displayed along with the message.

```
Drawable icon_error = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.icon_error);//this should be your error image.
icon_error.SetBounds(0,0,icon_error.IntrinsicWidth,icon_error.IntrinsicHeight);

if (txtsubiect.Text.Length <= 0)
                        {
                            txtsubiect.RequestFocus();
                            txtsubiect.SetError("Eroare,camp gol!", icon_error );
                        }
```